# some of my apps din't work including google play store after i rooted my galaxy s4

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, root-access

I rooted my samsung galaxy s4 and since then most off my apps din't start up including google playstore , but system apps like camera, music etc works fine 
 I Clear chache, data and other stuffs taking advice from youtube but it din't work still, i can't start some of my apps mostsly google related apps
 some of them inform me to restore the factoty setting. but before that can anyone help with my issue for which i will be very thankfull to u all.

Comment: First: how do you mean the apps don't start? Are the icons in the app drawer and nothing happens when you tap on them? Are you logged into your Google account? Second: how did you root your device? Are you stock or did you flash a new ROM? You may need to reinstall Gapps, then.

Comment: I just saw the "cyanogenmod" tag, so you should also mention exactly which ROM you are running. If you haven't already, flash the correct [Gapps](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps).

Comment: Hi! Why did you root Cyanogenmod which already comes with root access, albeit disabled? By apps not starting up, what exactly do you intend to say? 1) Are they not visible in app drawer? 2) Or, When you tap the app icon in app drawer, nothing happens? 3) Or something else? Give us the complete information with Android version, ROM version, and placing yourself in our shoes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reflash the ROM and the gapps (Reboot to custom recovery (install one if you haven't already) and select ROM flashable zip and then Gapps for your version of android.). (try rebooting and letting first-boot setup take place before flashing gapps. This is not required but may help). Also clear data, dalivik and cache again if required.

ROM: You need one for your phone model. Roms for different versions of same model i.e. International vs US Carrier vs Korean model, etc. wont work on each other.

GAPPS: gapps or google apps deffer based on your android version. i.e 4.1, 4.2, 4.4, etc. You can use same gapps on different phones as long as they have same android version as required by gapps downloaded.

Comment: Could you detail (steps needed) the first sentence? Please see [answer].